# Could oxidation of oil in frozen fish be causing smell which I am mistakening for overcooking?

Tags: fish, smell

I posted some questions about overcooking whitebait and am wondering if the cause of this smell, since it appears so quickly is overcooking or fish oil oxidation.  I found the following which makes me think it could be due to oil oxidation when freezing and hence not due to any overcooking:

*"In frozen fish, bacterial action is reduced to negligible levels but oxidation of the oil, especially in oily fish, will continue during storage and will lead to a loss of eating quality. Some of the proteins in fish undergo changes, not fully understood, during long periods of frozen storage which lead to undesirable toughening of the flesh."*

It's extremely difficult to get fresh whitebait so I have nothing to compare it against or verify that this is a frozen fish oxidation issue.  I am also sensitive to chemicals\smells so it could be that I can sense the oxidised oil wherease most people can't.

Comment: Everything else you've posted suggests that you're reliably overcooking your fish, so it's hard to really rule that out. But do you know what rancid oil smells/tastes like? It's not really something people have much trouble sensing in general.